# express - mysql - Reference error - query is not defined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, node-mysql

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to create a node server with mysql database. I have created the following files to establish the connection.

connect.js

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
var db;

const connectDatabase = () => {
  if (!db) {
    db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        port: '8889',
        database : 'testDb'
    });

db.connect(function(err){
  if(!err) {
      console.log('Database is connected!');
  } else {
      console.log('Error connecting database!', err);
  }
});


}
  return db;
}

export { connectDatabase, db};
```

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import logger from './core/logger/app-logger'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import config from './core/config/config.dev'
import user from './routes/user.route'
import {connectDatabase} from './db/connect'

const port = config.serverPort;
logger.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
        logger.info(message);
    }
};

connectDatabase();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan("dev", { "stream": logger.stream }));

app.use('/user', user);

//Index route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Invalid endpoint!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    logger.info('server started - ', port);
});
```

user.route.js

```
import express from "express";
import userController from "../controllers/user.controller"
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/allUsers', (req, res) => {
    userController.getAll(req, res);
});

export default router;
```

user.controller.js

```
import userModel from '../models/user.model';
import logger from '../core/logger/app-logger';

let userController = {};

userController.getAll = (req, res) => {
    try {
            const users = userModel.getAll();
            logger.info('sending all users...');
            console.log('sending all users...');
            res.send(users);
    }
    catch(err) {
            logger.error('Error in getting users- ' + err);
            console.log('Error in getting users- ' + err);
            res.send('Got error in getAll');
    }
}


export default userController;
```

user.model.js

```
import { db } from '../db/connect'
import mysql from 'mysql';

const userModel = {};

userModel.getAll = () => {

    db.query("select * from user",query, function(err, results, query) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return results;
    });
}

export default userModel;
```

when I try to run the userModel.getAll function, I was expecting the 'db' object to be already initialized( from the server.js).

But I am getting the following error from the user.model.js

```
Error in getting users- ReferenceError: query is not defined
```

I am not sure if I am exporting the connectDatabase and db properly from the connect.js

I am using ES6 standards for the project. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You've given way too much code IMO, and most SO users won't have the patience to sift through it.  Can you narrow down your question?

Comment: sure, I am trying to run the query "select * from user" in the user.model.js. I have imported the mysql connection object from the connect.js. But I am running into the error - ReferenceError: query is not defined -  when I try to use "db.query".  Please let me know if this helps you to get the gist of my problem.

Comment: @Humourprogrammer: your `query` call has wrong signature. it should be like `connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields)`. read at github https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

Comment: @RavinderReddy that was it! thank you :)

Comment: @Humourprogrammer: The one you used is applicable when there are some inputs, as place holeder vaues, to the query.